# Let me add or change edit summary during edit window (grace period)

Tags: feature-request, edits, grace-period, edit-summary

It often occurs to me to add an edit summary to a question-edit immediately *after* submitting the edit, especially if the changes aren't obvious (formatting etc.). So I:

1. Click "edit" again.
2. Fill in the summary
3. Click on "Save Edits".

The 'edit' (no actual change has been made to the title/body/tags)  is accepted, but the summary doesn't show up, i.e. it is silently rejected.

I don't think it should work this way because the summary has been added by the original editor within the original edit's edit-window. In fact if I remember correctly, it to used to work as expected earlier; so perhaps this is a recent change.

Comment: This is annoying - the only way around it that I know of is by changing something in the body along with the edit summary, then edit it immediately *again* to undo that particular change.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn It's easier to add or remove trailing space in some line -- no need to undo.

Comment: @Normal Human: That's what I do, but I don't like leaving stray whitespace in my edits, feels untidy.

Comment: You can always replace a return with `<br>`. No stray whitespace or visible edits needed!

Comment: Give 24 hours to edit Edit summary http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289244

Answer (score 7):

As noted in [this duplicate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96918/347902), it's possible to edit the edit summary during the grace period if you make at least one other edit at the same time. However, if the edit is all correct apart from the summary, it's strange to force a pointless edit just to be able to change the summary, and worth making the change to the edit summary itself work directly.

[This feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190431/347902) requested combining the edit summaries of the two edits, but was declined due to misunderstanding how a grace period edit works. The sentiment is still correct, though; what should happen is that a change to the edit summary during the grace period should be considered as an edit to the post, even if the post itself doesn't change.