# Can't edit revision comments

Tags: feature-request, edits, revisions-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to retroactively add edit summary during edit window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79180/unable-to-retroactively-add-edit-summary-during-edit-window)

I accidentally pressed enter while trying to type `'` and [submitted an edit with an incomplete comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/115841/revisions).

I tried simply editing again and changing the comment but this didn't work. The system always keeps the first revision comment you wrote.

In the same time you can edit your revision after submitting it, shouldn't you be allowed to change the edit comment as well?

Comment: Did you change the post at all in your subsequent edit? I think if you don't modify anything, your edit (and the new edit summary) is discarded directly instead of being merged.

Comment: @lunboks: No, I didn't. That could be the reason, but even in that scenario I would expect different behavior. Editing the comment should be considered part of editing your revision.

Comment: I agree. I've actually run into this issue before. One workaround (within the grace period, of course) is to add gibberish to the end of your post, then edit it out again.

Comment: Yes, it happens to me all the time. I wish this could be fixed.